# Remove vertical scrollbar in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

How can I remove this annoying expanding scrollbar in IB?

[image]

Everytime I want to change the tag or anything else on the far right I accidentally touch the scrollbar and it EXPANDS OVER THE BUTTON... apple... is it possible to remove it or disable it?

Comment: I think its not possible. Its like you want to ride a bike without petrol. If you still hates it so much then go ahead and set everything programmatically.

Comment: Just think apple should've thought of this before release